# How do I avoid getting "error during SQL execution : constraint failed" when I update my sqlite core data store?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

Our app lets the user choose a location from a list which is provided by an API.  The list updates infrequently and only by adding items, so instead of hitting the API every time, the app comes with a snapshot in a Core Data sqlite store, and we want it to periodically update the list.  The code to do so works like this:

- create a managed object context for the thread
- get the full list from the API
- for each one:

  - find the Location in the context with a matching locationID
  - if not found, insert a new one into the context
  - update the Location with the new information
- save the context

When starting with a blank DB, this works fine.  However, when we run it a second time it fails during the save with the message "error during SQL execution : constraint failed".  It does this even if I limit it to one location.  If I turn on SQL debugging, I see the following:

```
CoreData: sql: BEGIN EXCLUSIVE
CoreData: sql: COMMIT
CoreData: sql: BEGIN EXCLUSIVE
CoreData: sql: INSERT INTO ZLOCATION(Z_PK, Z_ENT, Z_OPT, ZGEOID, ZCOUNTY, ZCOUNTRYCODE, ZNAME, ZLATITUDE, ZLONGITUDE, ZLANGUAGECODE) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
CoreData: error: (19) constraint failed
CoreData: annotation: Disconnecting from sqlite database due to an error.
```

Then it reconnects and tries again a few times before giving up.

My code is definitely finding the old Locations and the objects are all valid - or at least [object validateForUpdate] returns YES.  What does the error mean?  Is there a way of finding out which constraint is failing?

If I use the binary store, the error goes away - but the binary store is atomic and blocks for ages on writes.  It looks like a bug in the sqlite store - has anyone found a workaround?

Comment: it may happens when you are trying to put null value in not cull field in database

Comment: would validateForUpdate not catch that?

Comment: I guess your "find the location in the context with a matching locationID" is failing to find the match even when it is available and your "if not found, insert a new one into the context" violating primary/unique constraint on locationId.

Comment: I wondered that, too - but I've checked, and it isn't.

Comment: Is there only one entity in your model?

Comment: No, there are quite a lot.  Location has a one-to-many relation with RecentLocation, but the code doesn't touch that relation.

Comment: Show your code. You should (almost) never have to look at the actual SQL database. Core Data is not a database.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I noticed that it was doing `INSERT INTO ZLOCATION` not `UPDATE ZLOCATION`, so I had a look at the bit where I was inserting the locations into the context.  I had:

```
if ([object isInserted])
{
    if (![object validateForUpdate:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Invalid object %@: %@, %@", object, error, [error userInfo]);   
        break;
    }
}
else
{
    if ([object validateForInsert:&error])
    {
        [context insertObject:object];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Invalid object %@: %@, %@", object, error, [error userInfo]);   
        break;
    }
}
```

What I didn't know is that, **for objects coming out of the database, `[object isInserted]` is false**.  So, I was inserting an already-inserted object and it was crashing as a result.  When I changed it to [object managedObjectContext], my problem went away.

Comment: Hey , i am facing same issue . can you help me please ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33365748/ios-coredata-unique-constraint-failed

Answer (score 1):

It's most likely a validation error. If you have custom validation code, check that.

A suprising number of weird errors with context result from problems with threads. I would run the code on the front thread. If it works, then you have a threading problem.

Comment: We've not got any custom validation code, and we get the same problem on the main thread.

Comment: Do you get the same problem if you run on the main thread without creating a new managedObjectContext?

Comment: I did - the problem turned out to be a double insert.