# What should I replace Core Data with?

Tags: ios, core-data, orm

I'm having [a problem updating our core data sqlite DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7385011).  So far our DB is only used to cache stuff coming back from our API, but with the next release of the app we're planning to save user data, so we need the DB to work, and unless I can fix that problem Core Data+sqlite just doesn't.  Hopefully we will, but just in case, I need to look at alternatives.

We need something that will do:

- Partial updates (so we can save 1 record without saving the whole DB)
- Migrations (so we can support upgrading old versions)
- Relationships (because our data has those)
- Transient objects (because we don't always want to save them to the DB)

We also need something which doesn't require too big a rewrite to our model classes - ideally we'd just change the superclass and go from there.  Bonus points if it's thread-safe.  Do you know of any ORMs for iOS that fit those criteria?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that [your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7385011) has been resolved satisfactorily. Core Data does all the things you mention out of the box, so you should not have any problem there.